# For each link, if the closest div with class "x" contains text "a" then replace part of link

Tags: javascript, jquery

I would like to change the link based on if the closest div with class `"div.companyName .dataText"` contains particular text. If the div contains VIP Company I would like to replace `"pg=tfind"` with `"pg=tfind&s_promoCode=vipteammate"`. If it contains Normal I would like to replace it with `"pg=tfind&s_promoCode=teammate"`. I have added the code below for 2 of the join links but there are multiple. Currently the script updates the link for both with vipteammate. The HTML is hardcoded and cannot be edited directly so this must be done using js.

Here is what I have so far:

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
  jQuery('.join .dataText a').each(function(){
     if($(this).closest('#team-listings').find('.companyName .dataText:contains("VIP Company")')){
     this.href = this.href.replace('pg=tfind', 'pg=tfind&s_promoCode=vipteammate');
     } else if($(this).closest('#team-listings').find('.companyName .dataText:contains("Normal")')) {
      this.href = this.href.replace('pg=tfind', 'pg=tfind&s_promoCode=teammate');
     }
  }); 
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="team-listings">
 <div class="companyName">
  <span class="dataText">
  VIP Company
  </span>
 </div>
 <div class="join">
  <span class="dataText">
   <a href="http://wwww.link.com?pg=tfind&fr=8939898">Join</a>
  </span>
 </div>
</div>

<div class="team-listings">
 <div class="companyName">
  <span class="dataText">
  Normal
  </span>
 </div>
 <div class="join">
  <span class="dataText">
   <a href="http://wwww.link.com?pg=tfind&fr=87349834">Join</a>
  </span>
 </div>
</div>
```

Ive been stuck for a while, any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: You're misunderstanding what `closest()` is.  https://api.jquery.com/closest  `closest()` only finds ancestors of an element.  Ancestors are parents of the element.  In this case, the companyName is not an ancestor to anything in the join element

Comment: ah ok, any suggestions on what I can use instead?

Comment: You can use closest to get the team-listings ancestor, and off of that guy, perform a find for the nested "thing" you want.

Comment: Also change `<div id="team-listings">` to `<div class="team-listings">`.  Repeating ids is invalid html by web standards, and javascript will hate you if you do that

Comment: @Jenny The path to being a good developer is to always read documentation when you use something you arent familiar with. jQuery and javascript in general are pretty well documented so when you use something new check [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/) for pure JS and [jQuerys official docs](https://api.jquery.com/) for jQuery

Answer (score 1):

You should find the closest #team-listing, then find the dataText element which contains VIP Company (or Normal).  Also in your if statement, you should check for length > 0 to determine if it is found.

I modified your snippet below

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.dataText a').each(function(index, item){
        if($(item).closest('#team-listings').find('.dataText:contains("VIP Company")').length > 0){
            this.href = this.href.replace('pg=tfind', 'pg=tfind&s_promoCode=vipteammate');
        } else if($(item).closest('#team-listings').find('.dataText:contains("Normal")').length > 0) {
            this.href = this.href.replace('pg=tfind', 'pg=tfind&s_promoCode=teammate');
        }
    }); 
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="team-listings">
 <div class="companyName">
  <span class="dataText">
  VIP Company
  </span>
 </div>
 <div class="join">
  <span class="dataText">
   <a href="http://wwww.link.com?pg=tfind&fr=8939898">Join</a>
  </span>
 </div>
</div>

<div id="team-listings">
 <div class="companyName">
  <span class="dataText">
  Normal
  </span>
 </div>
 <div class="join">
  <span class="dataText">
   <a href="http://wwww.link.com?pg=tfind&fr=87349834">Join</a>
  </span>
 </div>
</div>
```